# Populating data in dropdown menu

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I am new to c# so bit stuck at what I thought was a very simple module. I just need to display data in the dropdown menu but getting some error while binding... or I will say even before binding. Here is what I am trying to do..I am really sorry if I am doing a very simple mistake but I tried my best & now I think I need some guidance..

**CustomService.cs**

```
public partial class CustomService
{
public List<Code> GetDepartment(bool activeOnly)
    {
        List<Code> retVal = new List<Code>();
        ---some code----
        return retVal;
    }
     }
```

**ProgramList.ascx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            List<Code> dept = new List<Code>CustomService.GetDepartment(true);
            ddlDepartment.DataSource = dept;
            ddlDepartment.DataBind();
         }
    } 
   //error an object reference is required for an nonstatic field, method or Property CustomService.GetDepartment(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to create object first and than you can call the method

another thing is you just need to assign the value directly as i did below, there is no need to create any new list

check the code below that will work for you

```
CustomService custsrv = new CustomService();
List<Code> dept = custsrv.GetDepartment(true);
```

Comment: CustomService is a separate helper class in different project I have added the dll for that project using Prod.Integration.DataModel; on top of the page ...

Comment: do I still have to create an instance for it??

Comment: ok Now I dont have the error ..it compiles fine but I dont get the list of data in the drop down?? Sorry for another question

Answer (score 1):

To be able to call the method GetDepartment, you need to have a new instance of CustomService created:

```
CustomService service = new CustomService();
service.GetDepartment(true);
```

or to make the method static:

```
public static List<Code> GetDepartment(bool activeOnly) { }
```

However, if you put it static, every variables used by that method that reside inside the class will also need to be static.

Comment: GetDepartment is not static method

Comment: Ah! Sorry, didn't notice it was in a different class. What put me off is the lack of class definition around Page_Load

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help.

```
 CustomService custS = new CustomService();
    ddlDepartment.DataSource = custS.GetDepartment(true);
    ddlDepartment.DataBind();
```